# Shell32 GetDetailsOf Localization issue

Tags: winapi

Is there a reliable way to identify the filetype of a file across Windows platforms?

I've inherited a program which queries filetypes using the Shell32 GetDetailsOf function, which returns localized strings and causes an error if a non-english system is used (for example, on a german system GetDetailsOf(item,9) returns "Bild" instead of "Image").

Comment: Can you define "filetype"?

Comment: Filetype as in "Image","Video","Text","Executable" and so on.

Comment: That's not a definition at all. Is it alright if I return "Image" for every file? No, I didn't think so. How do you want the program to decide what the file type is.

Comment: Well, basically the program currently opens an editor based on the filtetype returned from the shell function. So if it's an image file, it uses some WPF function for images, same for videos, audio, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the textual description of a filetype is not a reliable way of identifying particular types of file. As you've noticed the description strings change from language to language, but they can also change within the one language depending on the software the user has installed (as a made up example, a .jpg file might have the description "JPEG image" on one system, and "Adobe Photoshop Image" on another system if the user has installed software that claims the filetypes and changes the description).

Instead, your best way of identifying the filetype is to look at the file's extension (`.jpg` in our example). What you do with it then is up to you and depends on your application. You might just have a hard-coded list of extensions that you work with, or to be more generic you could look in the registry for the filetype's "perceived type":

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg\PerceivedType

To see if that value is set to "image", "audio", etc.

Comment: Well, that's what I needed to clarify. I checked the description on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx, but it doesn't even mention the iColumn parameter that is being used here. I noticed, for example, that 2 gives me the "Paint.NET image" (as you mentioned), but passing 9 returns "Image" and 11 "Picture".

Comment: This seems like a pretty sane approach.

Comment: I guess looking at the file extensions is the way to go. Thanks guys.